# How to make delete-all button in flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've been trying to make a delete-all button for my flask web application. So far, I've only successfully made a delete button that deletes things one after the other:

```
@controllers.route('/delete-note/<int:id>', methods=[ 'DELETE' ])
def delete_note(id):
    activity = json.loads( request.data )
    print(activity)
    activity_id = activity[ 'activity_id' ]
    activity = UserActivity.query.get( activity_id )

    if activity:
        if activity.uid == current_user.id:
            db.session.delete( activity )
            db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({"status": True})
```

this is my saved.py file, the user picks which activities are saved into this file:

```
        <button type='button' class='close' style='align-self: flex-end;padding: 1.2em;' onclick="deleteAll()"
        <span>Delete All</span>
        </button>  
        <ul class='flex-container wrap' id='saved_notes'>
              {% if data %}
                {%for ua in data%}
                <form method='DELETE'>
                    <li class='flex-item' style ='padding: 1.2rem;' id="act-{{ua.id}}">
                        <div>
                            <button type='button' class='close' onclick="deleteNote(`{{ua.id}}`)">
                                &times;
                            </button>
                            <button type='button' class='close' onclick="completed()">
                                <span>&#10004;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                            <div style='width: 20em;'>
                                <span>Activity: </span>{{ ua.activity [ 'activity' ] }}
                            </div>
                            
                            <div><span>Activity-type: </span>{{ ua.activity[ 'type' ] }}</div>
                            <div><span>Number of people needed: </span>{{ ua.activity['participants'] }}</div>
                            <div><span>Price: </span>{{ ua.activity['price'] }}</div>
                            {% if ua.activity['link']|length %} 
                                <div><span>Link: </span><a href = "{{ ua.activity['link'] }}">Click me!</a></div>
                            {% endif %}    
                    </li>
                    <!-- end of act ua id -->
                </form>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
```

And this is the JavaScript behind the deleteNote function:

```
const deleteNote = id => fetch(`/delete-note/${id}`,{
    method: 'DELETE',
    body: JSON.stringify({ activity_id: id})
}).then((_res) =>{
    $(`#act-${id}`).remove();
    alert("deleted " + id)
})
```

Is there any way I can implement the 'deleteAll()' function?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
@controllers.route('/delete-notes/', methods=['GET'])
def delete_notes():
    num_activities_deleted = db.session.query(UserActivity).delete()
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({"num_activities_deleted ": num_activieties_deleted })
```

and js:

```
const deleteNotes = id => fetch(`/delete-notes/`,{
    method: 'GET'
}).then((_res) =>{
    $(`#act-`).remove();
    alert("deleted: " + num_activities_deleted + " activities" )
})
```

Comment: Thank you su much! But may I ask how I would go about implementing this in my JavaScript..
How I would use the remove function on all of the notes

Comment: Maybe this js is what you meant.

Comment: Thank you so much! The web page still doesn't reload even after using:
``` 
window.location.href = '/saved';

```
in the function you wrote, although the 'Delete All' button does work except for the fact that I have to manually reload the page.